# Loop over mysql rows

Tags: php, mysql

If I have a mysql table looking like this:

```
+-------+
| id    |
+-------+
|  3173 | 
| 31793 | 
| 58528 | 
+-------+
```

How do I loop over all the ids in PHP?

Comment: did you try fetch rows first? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=fetch+rows+from+mysql+in+php&submit=search

Comment: RTFM. google. there are *zillions* of examples.

Comment: Google: [`About 17,600,000 results (0.30 seconds)`](http://www.google.de/#hl=en&q=Loop+over+mysql+rows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I would recommend you to read some tutorials!*

---

#### 1.) Connect to your database

```
mysql_connect('server', 'username', 'password') or die( mysql_error() );
mysql_select_db('db-name') or die( mysql_error() );
```

#### 2.) `SELECT id FROM table_name`

```
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM table_name';
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error() );

$IDs = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row($result) )
{
  $IDs[] = $row[0];
}

print_r($IDs); // Output the IDs
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this, but probably you should do some tutorials

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT id FROM tablename');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo $row['id']; // this is the ID
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to the database:

```
$link = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);
```

Then retrieve a query result with the connection link

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT id FROM my_table_name WHERE 1', $link);
```

Then iterate threw the rows

```
while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) != false)
{
    // Do whatever you want with the id
    echo $row['id'];
}
```